# Authentication windows/JWT with .net core & angular 7

Tags: c#, angular, typescript, asp.net-core

I have configured .net core 2.2 startup file as follows:

```
var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(AppSettings.Secret);
        services.AddAuthentication(x =>
        {
            x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            x.DefaultChallengeScheme = 
 JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddJwtBearer(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, x =>
        {
            x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            x.SaveToken = true;
            x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
                ValidateIssuer = false,
                ValidateAudience = false
            };
        });
```

And in the configure method:

```
app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseMvc();
```

I am using .net core APIs through my Angular 7 SPA application and calls my API method :

```
   this.http.get<User>(path + 'api/' + 'users', { withCredentials: true })
```

Now when I access the angular application first time, the API call fails with 401 error in logs, but on the network tab it shows status as (failed), however If I just reload the application, it works. Then this error is randomly happening and I can only reproduce this error again if I try to access the application in the incognito mode.

This issue is only reproducible on deployed applications on the windows web servers with Anonymous and windows authentication set to true.

I haven't done any change corresponding to program.cs and it's the default configuration of .net core 2.2 there.

I have searched a lot on google, tried all the suggestions available, but none worked.

Is there any other place I need to look ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to send the token with the header to asp.net core controller so that the server know who you are.

Store the token in localStorage and append into the header

Update:

Try to update your code like this to see if it work

```
   this.http.get<User>(path + 'api/' + 'users')
```

Comment: The token is being send correctly to JWT. It's just that when I access the application first time, it request the token through an API which is windows authentication protected. There I am having this random problem mentioned in the actual question. Once the token gets generated, rest of the API access work fine

Comment: May be you should remove withCredentials in your angular

Comment: removing withCredentials from angular will not send windows credential to API. It is required.

Comment: I added a retry(1) in the call so that it makes a request again if it fails, it shows that first request fails however now second request works fine and code works. This is a bad way to solve it but working for now.

Comment: Hmm seem like there are some problem of your authentication flow